# CRM 2011 Contact activity listed under lead

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Firstly background on how we use our CRM lead entity.

We treat each lead as a potential new customer and log contacts against the lead for each service we sell.

So a lead might have 3 contacts linked to it, 1 is head of IT 1 is Head of finance and 1 is the purchaser.

This works well however any email sent to the contact linked to the lead does not show up in the closed activity of the lead.

Does anyone know how to link a closed activity regarding a contact in to the closed activity of a lead. The lead and contact have been connected by creating a lookup in each entity.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using SDK we could use on demand workflow to re-open the closed activity and then update the regarding field to the lead, then mark it as complete.

Reference: http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/marcellotonarelli/archive/2013/09/02/re-open-closed-task-phone-call-email-or-activities-in-ms-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx

I hope it helps.